# change the return key

Tags: android, android-keypad

I want to change the name of enter button (the button circled in the image ) to search

[image]

so I used

```
  <EditText
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                android:imeActionLabel="Search"


                android:id="@+id/et_PatientID"

                android:layout_width="400dip"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_patientID"
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background" />
```

but it didn't work

Comment: try adding android:inputType="text", see updated answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `android:imeOptions="actionSearch"` and `android:inputType="text"` to your EditText View

also add the editor action listener

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
            performSearch();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});

<EditText 
            android:id="@+id/et_PatientID"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_width="400dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_patientID"
            android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch" 
            android:imeActionLabel="Search"  />
```

Comment: @AMH remove imeOptions= "acionUnspecified"

Comment: @AMH wich android version did you use

Comment: I used android 2.2 , I develope on to target it and higher

Comment: it worked thanks a lot ,I think I was in need to clean the project am sorry

Comment: @AMH I don't think this will work, you can try it and let me know :D, sorry I haven't eclipse in front of me

Comment: thanks a lot it worked could u help me in my new question please

Comment: @AMh of Course if I can, paste a link to it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13266/discussion-between-k-anas-and-amh)